# Why "onReset()" method called twice?

Tags: gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform

So I have following presenter and it shows "reset" twice, I need to fix that problem...There is no call of onReset() in my presenter, by the way onReset is protected excluding probability of calling this method from anywhere else. Does anyone know solution of such problem?

```
        @ProxyStandard
        interface MyProxy extends Proxy<ApplicationPresenter> {
        }

        @Inject
        ApplicationPresenter(){...}

        @Override
        protected void onBind() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReveal() {     
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReset() {
            Window.alert("reset");
        }
```

Comment: This happens usually if there is a listener that is registered twice.

Comment: What do you mean?Which a listener?

Comment: A click-handler for example. attached to the ui twice.